# ColdFusion: Object with duplicate values (removing duplicates)

Tags: object, coldfusion, duplicates

I have a query object (SQL) with some records, the problem is that some of the records contain duplicate values. :( (I can't use DISTINCT in my SQL Query, so how to remove in my object?)

categories[1].id = 1
categories[2].id = 1
categories[3].id = 2
categories[4].id = 3
categories[5].id = 2

Now I want to get a list with 1, 2, 3

Is that possible?

Comment: Why can't you use DISTINCT? Depending on where the duplicates came from you might need to fix the SQL joins - but you've not shown what your SQL looks like.

Comment: because it's not my SQL-Query, comes from a module outside my framework. :/

Comment: Adam showed you one way to do it - query of queries.  Depending on your situation, you might be better off with list functions.  cflib.org has one called ListDistinct() that will do the trick.

Comment: Then the correct phrase is not _"I can't use DISTINCT in my SQL-Query"_ but rather _"The data comes from an SQL query outside my control"_ - and the solution to filter it using what's known as a query of query (QoQ), as Adam shows below.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not quite sure why you say you can't use `DISTINCT`, even given the qualification you offered. It doesn't matter were a query came from (`<cfquery>`, `<cfldap>`, `<cfdirectory>`, built by hand) by the time it's exposed to your CFML code, it's just "a query", so you can definitely use `DISTINCT` on it:

```
<cfquery name="distinctCategories" dbtype="query">
    SELECT DISTINCT id
    FROM categories
</cfquery>
```

Comment: To be clear - the code above should be run AFTER you have made whatever call you need to make to get the query. So you have a query named "categories" and you use query of a query to _further_ filter the query down to the data set you need.

Comment: NP - some folks just aren't as familiar with the Q of a Q concept. It's a nice unique feature about CF that I really like.